# Group and summarise character in R?

Tags: r

I this in R

```
> con_promedio_por_curso_transpuesta
                A          B          C           D
Description   "Abc"     "Bcd"      "Cde"      "Def"
mean(X7)  "5.000000" "4.105263" "4.733333"  "4.680000"
mean(X8)  "5.000000" "3.736842" "4.400000"  "4.760000"     
mean(X9)  "5.000000" "3.950000" "4.600000"  "4.840000"
mean(X10) "5.000000" "4.210526" "4.333333"  "4.560000"
```

I want to delete the first row

```
"Abc"     "Bcd"      "Cde"      "Def"
```

I run the next instruction:

```
without_first_row <- con_promedio_por_curso_transpuesta[-c(1),])
```

Until now, everything is OK, but.  If I want to group and summarise the without_first_row I get an error.

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'character')"

I run the type of data,

```
> typeof(con_promedio_por_curso_transpuesta)
[1] "character"
```

How I cast "character" to any type of data for grouping ?

Thanks.

Comment: A quick solution is to use a `Dataframe` instead of `matrix`.

Comment: `Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method ...` as `group_by` used in `dataframe` and `tibble` but you have a matrix. So just use `as.data.frame(con_promedio_por_curso_transpuesta[-c(1),])`

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your syntax near where you create `without_first_row`, follow along below:

```
con_promedio_por_curso_transpuesta <-
  data.frame(
    row.names = c('Description','mean(X7)','mean(X8)','mean(X9)','mean(X10)'),
    'A' = c("Abc","5.000000","5.000000","5.000000","5.000000"),
    'B' = c("Bcd","4.105263","3.736842","3.950000","4.210526"),
    'C' = c("Cde","4.733333","4.400000","4.600000","4.333333"),
    'D' = c("Def","4.680000","4.760000","4.840000","4.560000"),
    'ID' = c(NA, 1, 1, 2, 2) # added for this example
  )

## without_first_row <- con_promedio_por_curso_transpuesta[-c(1), ]) <- this is your error, you added a ')' unnecessarily

without_first_row <- con_promedio_por_curso_transpuesta[-c(1), ] # with fixed syntax
> class(without_first_row)
[1] "data.frame"


# just to show you can group_by and summarise with data
without_first_row %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(c(A,B,C,D)), funs(as.numeric)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean)
```